# How do I amplify, if possible, a digital USB signal from a sound board to Logic Pro, all via USB?

Tags: mac, usb, audio

In our church, we have an Alesis digital board which sends all channels to an external recording media.  The board output we use is USB, and the receiving media is Logic Pro on a Macbook Air.

We recently decreased our gain on the board channels to lower the strain and reduce feedback.  A result is lower volume on the signal of the recorded channels in Logic Pro.

Is there a USB interface that will bring the volume up on the USB-carried signal?

We have already maxxed out the input level on Logic Pro, and we want some wiggle room on levels for each channel, since we mix it down for our music podcast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As whatever you do to it post-Alesis will bring the noise floor up, it doesn't really matter where else you do it.

Simplest might be to put a 'maximiser' [I use [Waves L3 Ultra- or Multimaximiser](http://www.waves.com/plugins/l3-multimaximizer#introduction-to-the-l3-and-l3-ll-multimaximizers) but there are many alternatives] across the last insert in the Master Bus & just wind in some threshold until it brings the levels up without actually appearing to compress [You'll hear & see when it does, it's hard-knee]..

If the noise floor becomes audible, then perhaps one of the [de-noisers](http://www.waves.com/plugins/noise-reduction-restoration#sort:path~type~order=.default-order~number~asc%7Cviews:view=list-view%7Cpaging:currentPage=0%7Cpaging:number=20) [again, there are many varieties & manufacturers] earlier in the chain to compensate

*Edit:* & work at 32-bit float, if possible, or at least 24-bit, to minimise the amount of noise you will bring up due to simple number crunching inside the DAW.

Comment: This is an extremely helpful answer.  Wouldn't have thought maximizing then compensating for the additional noise would be suitable approach.

Comment: @Ramhound - actually, de-noise first, but only to cover for if you are actually hitting the compressor at all. It's easier to denoise a constant noise level than a changing one, of course, algorithmically - even though these days it's not impossible to do afterwards. [I *love* modern processing, makes my life so much easier;)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend editing the audio files after recording. You can always amplify the signal coming from an analog source, but that will introduce noise to the mix.

The best solution would be to edit the digital audio file in an audio editing software environment, where altering the file would result in no loss of fidelity. Audacity is one I have heard of, but no personal experience. I hope it works out!

Comment: Most of this answers seems like an answer.  It doesn't actually even begin to explain how to accomplish what you suggest.  A full tutorial isn't required but an answer that has more substance is often rewarded and extremely helpful.